# Is this a slang word and what does it mean? 摊牌

Tags: translation

I'm wondering if 摊牌 is a slang word, as when I translate it, I get the word "showdown". It doesn't make much sense to me when I try to translate within a sentence. So what I think this word means is to "come clean" based on what I have found online, but I want to make sure.

Here is an example:

您这是不装了…… 真摊牌了是吧？！

My translation:

Your not pretending... are you finally coming clean?

Another example:

这种摊牌方式……
一看就是个恶魔！

My translation:

This confession method...
a demon at first glance.

I don't really know if that is correct or if I'm mistaken.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suppose you used Google translate to get *showdown*. Actually, *showdown* here refers to the slang/jargon used in poker, i.e. laying all one's cards on the table / reveal one's hand, not the common English meaning of *showdown*.

Comment: Yeah I did, thanks so much for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**摊牌** - (as in a poker game), **show what** (card) **you have**; reveal something that one thinks is advantageous/beneficial (winning cards) to one's position/situation in a negotiation/confrontation.

Comment: 摊牌 = lay the (concealed) card (on the table) = reveal your concealed card.

It came from 'show-hand' (Texas Holdem)- a popular poker game among the Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are correct, 摊牌 is indeed a slang in poker games. However, as in daily life, it means someone is not pretending no more, it's like letting everyone know what cards you have in ur hands.